# Improper integral for a one sided limit (Using CT)

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Question: Determine if the integral is conv. or div.

Integral : $$\int_{5}^{6} \frac{1}{(x-3)(x-5)^{1/2}} dx$$

Firstly I needed to figure if the $f(x)$ was divergent or convergent. And so, I tried subbing in the limit values, and found that x = 5 becomes 1/0 which is indeterminent form. So I added a limit to the integral, A, where A approaches $5^+$ and subbed it again. This gave me infinity, which implies divergence. However, I graphed $f(x) = 1/(x-3)(x-5)^{1/2} $ and it looked like: http://puu.sh/zE9yH/ef90963004.png .
This is where I'm confused.... If $x = 5^+$, $f(x) = inf $, and $x= 6, f(x) = constant$, where there is no V.A. in between, then isn't f(x) convergent? This is just the rough work of the equation, I cannot move onto the next step where I solve the integral of g(x) > f(x) or f(x) < g(x) without knowing this...

Can anybody answer my question? Thanks!

Or if somebody could provide a detailed solution I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
0\leq \int_5^6\frac{1}{(x-3)\sqrt{x-5}}\mathrm dx\leq\frac{1}{2}\int_5^6(x-5)^{-1/2}\mathrm dx
$$
Now 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_5^6(x-5)^{-1/2}\mathrm dx=\sqrt{x-5}\bigg\vert_5^6=1-\lim_{x\to 5^+} \sqrt{x-5}=1
$$

Comment: Yes.. But I don't get it... is the integral convergent or divergent? In your equation, i'm guessing it's convergent since you found an integral, g(x) larger than f(x)

Comment: If I change the limit to $x=5^+$, and the integrand goes to infintity, is the integrand f(x) conv or div? considering the upper/lower bound

Comment: the integrand going to infinity tells you that the integral is improper, you have to work harder to figure out if it converges. I'll finish the solution

Comment: Yes, I bounded an integral you are worried is not finite

Comment: I am aware that it is improper. However, to apply CT it is common to simplify f(x) so that it is an easier function to integrate. In order to find that function, you first need to determine if the integrand is conv or div, so you don't mess up.My point is that I found that the integrand goes to infinity when I sub x = 5+, WHICH IS DIVERGENT, but when I solve the integral it becomes a constant WHICH IS convergent.. This is madly confusing to me...

Comment: You are confusing the limit of the integrand with the limit of the integrals, these are not the same thing. $1/\sqrt{x}$ does indeed tend to infinity as $x\to 0$, but it's integral from $0$ to $1$ is finite. You care about the speed at which the integrand tends to infinity.

Comment: "In order to find that function, you first need to determine if the integrand is conv. or div." I don't know what you mean by this. I bounded the integrand by something larger, without any use of the integrand having infinite limit.

Comment: @user498021 also, you are not simplifying $f$, you are *bounding* it

Answer (score 0):

Observe that in a neighbourhood of $5$ the function's singularity behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$. More precisely
$$
\lim_{x\to5}\frac{1/[(x-3)\sqrt{x-5]}}{1/\sqrt{x-5}}=2
$$
Since
$$
\int_{5}^6\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}\,dx=\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx<\infty
$$
It follows that your integral is finite too by the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is skirting the issue of the discontinuity by using a substitution which makes it go away, but if we let $u^2=x-5$ then $2u\,du=dx$ and the integral becomes

$$ 2\int_0^1\frac{du}{u^2+2} $$

which is elementary.